# Why viewData value is not printing success message

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am passing a message using view data after successful user creation I am getting the data over view there but its not printing the value what I am getting over there, can not find the issue. Please help with whats wrong.
Here is my code:

**View:**

```
@model App.ViewModels.ConfigMyViewModel
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#openPopup').click(function () {
        var companyLogo = $('#ConfigMy_CompanyLogo').prop('checked');
        var iFrameWidth = $('#ConfigMy_IFrameWidth').val();
        var iFrameHeight = $('#ConfigMy_IFrameHeight').val();
        var req = { "CompanyLogo": companyLogo,"IFrameWidth": iFrameWidth, "IFrameHeight": iFrameHeight };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "ConfigMyApp")',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(req),
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var test = '@Url.Action("Index", "Order", new { area = "", UID = ViewData["UIDforUser"] }, this.Request.Url.Scheme)';
                var result = '<iframe width="' + iFrameWidth + '" height="' + iFrameHeight + '" src="' + test + '"></iframe>';
                $("#iframeDiv").show();
                $("#textIframe").val(result);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error: Dynamic content load failed.");
            }
        });       
    });
    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ConfigMyApp", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "configpre" }))
{
<div class="row" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
        <div class="dummyMessageHead col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            @ViewData["MessageText"]
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" id="company">
                                <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm notActive">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ConfigMy.CompanyLogo, true)
                                </label>
                                <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ConfigMy.CompanyLogo, false)
                                </label>
                                &nbsp;Company Logo
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                            IFrame Width 
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfigMy.IFrameWidth, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                            IFrame Height 
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfigMy.IFrameHeight, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
            </div>
 <div>
                        <button type="button" id="openPopup" class="btn btn-danger">@Html.CustomText("btnGenerate", "Generate and Copy Code")</button>
                    </div>
                @* Panel Ends *@
                <div class="row" style="display: none" id="iframeDiv">
                    <div class="col-md-11 col-sm-11">
                        <input type="text" id="textIframe" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1">
                        @*<button type="button" id="closeIframeDiv"class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>close</button>*@
                        <a href="#" id="closeIframeDiv" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

                ConfigMyViewModel = configMyViewModel = new ConfigMyViewModel();
                if (Session["Message"] != null)
                {
                    ViewData["MessageText"] = Session["Message"].ToString();
                    Session["Message"] = null;
                }
                return View("Index",configMyPreFlightViewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Account", new { area = "" });
            }
        }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ConfigMy configMy,,bool CompanyLogo,, int IFrameWidth, int IFrameHeight)
        {
                ConfigMyViewModel configMyViewModel = new ConfigMyViewModel();
        bool exists = db.ConfigMys.Any(row => row.UserId == 2);
if (exists != true)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        configMy.CompanyLogo = CompanyLogo;
                        configMy.IFrameWidth = IFrameWidth;
                        configMy.IFrameHeight = IFrameHeight;
                        string MessageText = configMyService.AddPre(configMy);
                        Session["Message"] = MessageText;
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", configMyViewModel);
               }
                else
                {
                    var query = from p in db.ConfigMys
                     where p.UserId == 2
                     select p;
                    foreach (ConfigMy p in query)
                    {
                        p.CompanyLogo = CompanyLogo;
                        p.IFrameWidth = IFrameWidth;
                        p.IFrameHeight = IFrameHeight;
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        string MessageText = "PreFlight Updated Successfully";
                        Session["Message"] = MessageText;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                   return RedirectToAction("Index", configMyViewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SignIn", "Account", new { area = "" });
            }
        }
```

**Method of service:**

```
public string AddPre(ConfigMy configMy)
        {
            string messageText = "<div class=\"row\" style=\"border:1px solid #87CB96; background-color:#CAF9BE; vertical-align:central;\"><p><ul>";
            db.ConfigMys.Add(configMy);
            db.SaveChanges();
            messageText += string.Format("<li>Flight Successfully Added</li>");
            messageText += "</ul></p></div>";
            return messageText;
        }
```

Everything is working fine except the viewdata value is not printing it in the respecive div but i am getting the value in viewdata . 
[image: heres the value i am getting]
What's wrong here? Can anyone figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

1. `Html.parseHtml` is not a built-in. If you've made your own helper, you need to post that code here. As it stands, your main problem may be in that.
2. If you need to temporarily save a bit of data for the next request, use `TempData`, not `Session`.
3. There's no point in setting `ViewData` with the value from either `Session` or `TempData` as you can use `Session` or `TempData` directly in your view.

Comment: here is my helper class ..
 public static IHtmlString parseHtml(this HtmlHelper helper, string HtmlText)
        {
            return new HtmlString(HtmlText);
        }

Comment: Yeah. That is a totally useless extension. Just use `Html.Raw`.

Comment: sir actually the main problem is i am using jquery ajax, and it is creating the dynamic iframe on success , so the page is not refreshing or not redirecting to the particular given location.. sir can you please analyze my code and confirm how can i get the success message.. i have updated my code

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this , instead of using `@Html.parseHtml`

```
<div class="dummyMessageHead col-md-12 col-sm-12">
 ViewData["MessageText"]
</div>
```

`Razr` will generate the `Html` accordingly using the `ViewData` attribute.

If you need to parse your html you can use:`@Html.Raw()`

here's an example:

```
@Html.Raw("<script>alert('Parsed html');</script>")
```

This last line of code will be processed as parsed `HTML` and not text